# Pivot table criteria to select all values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pivot-table, google-sheets-api

I'm using Google Apps Script to create a pivot table, and I can specify the filter criteria to select specific values:

```
"criteria": {
   1: {"visibleValues": ["value1", "value2"]} 
 }
```

How can I select all the values without listing all of them in the "visibleValues" field?  Is there something like regular expressions to do such simple task?

Answer (score 1):

Just don't include the filter criteria.

```
"criteria": {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I needed to list in the criteria all the unique values of a column, so the filter is created in the Pivot Table, and all the records are visible by default.

With Ruben's solution, `"criteria": {},` the filter is created, but all the values are hidden, so you have to make them visible manually.
After some research, I'm afraid there's no an easy way to do this. The only way to set a filter criteria is with "visibleValues": https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/PivotFilterCriteria.

My solution was this: I collected all the unique values of my column in an array, and then set the filter with

```
"criteria": {
   1: {"visibleValues": myArrayOfUniqueValues } 
 }
```

Hope this helps!